# Custom Page Layouts Assigned Only To Top Level Categories Are Being Applied To Subcategories?

Tags: magento-1.9, category

I have created a new template for a custom `Page Layout` to apply to the top-level categories only, using a custom module.

Here is my module/etc/config.xml file from the module (I am not posting the template or the /etc/module/xml file as I don't believe they are relevant. Let me know if you'd like to see them and I will edit):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Action_ToplevelcatLayout>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Action_ToplevelcatLayout>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <page>
            <layouts>
                <top_level_category_layout_name translate="label">
                    <label>New Top Level Category Layout</label>
                    <template>page/top-level-category-layout.phtml</template>
                    <layout_handle>top-level-category-layout</layout_handle>
                </top_level_category_layout_name>
            </layouts>
        </page>
    </global>
</config>
```

I assigned this new page layout to all of the top level categories one by one by changing the option selected in the `Page Layout` dropdown of the `Custom Design` tab to the new page template - and that works great...**but it seems to work too great actually**.

The problem I'm having is the subcategories are also inheriting this new `Page Layout`, which is have only been assigned to it's parent. `Use Parent Category Settings` on subcategories are set to **No**.

**I can resolve this issue by saving the child categories**. If I save them (even without making any changes) the default page template is then reapplied to the subcategories and then work as expected.

Have I done something incorrect here or am I missing something? Why are the subcategories inheriting the parent category page template if it has not been assigned to it? I have also assigned the default template in the local.xml file:

```
<catalog_category_layered> 
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_layered>

<catalog_category_default> 
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_default>
```

If this is what I have to work with, how can I iterate through all of the categories and resave them safely without having to do so manually? I have hundreds of second level categories and really hope to avoid having to manually resave them. Thanks for your help!

**UPDATE:**

If I disable `Use Flat Catalog Category`, then both the top-level and subcategories use the correct `Page Layout` template. How can I ensure that the subcategories use the correct `Page Layout` template when `Use Flat Catalog Category` is also enabled? Is there an attribute that I need to modify?